# android exoplayer2 add subtitle when video playing

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I want add subtitle to video when playing

This code add subtitle before play video:

```
Format textFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(null, MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP, null, Format.NO_VALUE, Format.NO_VALUE, "en", null, Format.OFFSET_SAMPLE_RELATIVE);
MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(selectedfile)
                    .createMediaSource(selectedfile, textFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);
MergingMediaSource mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);
player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
```

How can I add subtitle when video playing like VLC or KMPlayer?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1649) in exoplayer github about your question. It seems that it's not possible to achieve this functionality right now.